# JSON string without keys - how to update MYSQL database related values

Tags: php, mysql, json, string

How can I update MYSQL database values with an JSON string that does not contain keys to identify the data? What I need is to use the first value of the JSAON data (e.g. "100", "200", "300", etc.) to find the correct line in the database, and update the database row with all the other values from the JSON data.

I've thought of parsing the data but I don't know how to do that without the key reference in the JSON data.

```
[
["100", "Salg, avgiftspliktig", "", "", "3000", ""],
["200", "Salg, avgiftsfritt", "", "", "3100", "I"],
["280", "", "", "", "", ""],
["300", "SUM SALG", "TOT", "100+200", "", "B"],
["500", "Varekjøp", "", "", "4300", ""],
["600", "SUM UTGIFTER", "TOT", "500", "", "B"],
["700", "", "", "", "", ""],
["800", "Driftsresultat", "TOT", "300-500", "", "B"],
["900", "", "", "", "", ""],
["1000", "", "", "", "", ""],
["1100", "cvzxb", "", "", "", ""],
["1200", "", "", "", "", ""]
]
```

Example update:

Database old data (from ID=800):
800,OldData,TOT,200,,I

Database updated value from the JSON data:
800,Driftsresultat,TOT,300-500,,B

Comment: Did you tried decoding your JSON to a PHP array with indexes equal to your IDs?

Comment: what is your table structure? also, please explain above JSON array, which element is mapped to which column in table?

Comment: _"does not contain keys to identify the data"_ - In your example, isn't `800` the identifier? Or do you mean that the json data simply has indexed arrays instead of objects? It seems like the data is in the same order though so just go by the index.

Comment: Magnus; yes, the "800" in the example is the identifier, but how may I use that identifier for each line in the example, find the identical row in the DB (row with id 800) and update the other values from the JSON data on that row?